# Beckenbach Introduction to Inequalities Chapter 2: Show $(a+b)/2 \le ( (a^2 + b^2 )/2)^{1/2}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I'm having trouble understanding the following problem

**Problem**

> Beckenbach, Chapter 2 Pg 24 Ex 1
>   $$
> \text{Show the following for all a, b}\quad
> \frac{(a+b)}{2} \le \left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2}
> $$

The book provides answers in the back, the answer is shown as

$$
\text{equivalent to}\quad(a - b)^2 \ge 0
$$

**My attempt**

Thanks to this answer: [Proving the inequality $\frac{a+b}{2} - \sqrt{ab} \geq \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}} - \frac{a+b}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382988/proving-the-inequality-fracab2-sqrtab-geq-sqrt-fraca2b22?rq=1) I was able to show the following

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b}{2} &\le \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}} \\
\frac{a+b}{2} &\le \sqrt{\frac{(a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2}{4}}\\
\frac{a+b}{2} &\le \sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\left(1 + \left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2\right)}\\
\frac{a+b}{2} &\le \frac{a+b}{2}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2}\\
0 &\le \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2} - 1 \\
\text{Since}\quad\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2 \ge 0\quad\text{we're done}
\end{align}
$$

This feels ugly and I don't think is the way Beckenbach intended us to solve, considering this is in Chapter 2.

**Question**

> 1. Is my attempt valid?
> 2. Is there a more elegant way to show this, using $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$?

Thanks

Comment: Yes but better is to square both sides

Comment: @MostafaAyaz But then you lose the equivalence unless you deal with the non-negativity first.

Comment: In fact it suffices to prove it for non negatives (why?)

Answer (score 1):

If left side is not positive then inequality obviously hold.

So assume it is nonegative. Square it: $${a^2+2ab+b^2\over 4}\leq {a^2+b^2\over 2}$$

Get rid of denumerators and you get

$$ a^2+2ab+b^2\leq 2a^2+2b^2$$

or $(a-b)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: But... squaring is not valid unless you at least mention the fact that $a+b$ can be negative. The OP proceeds by equivalences, and that is not a good step for that.

Comment: Well if left side is not positive then inequality obviously hold.

Comment: @ChistianF Hence my mentioning "unless you at least mention the fact". it holds, but it needs to be said otherwise the chain of equivalences is wrong. And, typically, a grader in an introductory math class will point it out and take some points off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your proof has a tiny issue you need to address (and then it'll be correct): you forgot absolute values around $\frac{a+b}{2}$ once you factor $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$ out of the square root.
2. Note that
   $$
   \frac{a+b}{2} \leq \frac{\lvert a\rvert +\lvert b\rvert}{2}\tag{1}
   $$
   so it suffices to prove
   $$
   \frac{\lvert a\rvert +\lvert b\rvert}{2} \leq\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^{1/2} \tag{2}
   $$
   Square both sides of (2): this is equivalent, this everything is non-negative: so (2) is equivalent to
   $$
   \frac{a^2+b^2+2\lvert a\rvert\lvert b\rvert}{4} \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}
   $$
   in turn equivalent to
   $$
   a^2+b^2+2\lvert a\rvert\lvert b\rvert \leq 2a^2+2b^2
   $$
   in turn equivalent to
   $$
   0 \leq a^2+b^2+2\lvert a\rvert\lvert b\rvert \tag{3}
   $$
   and the RHS is equal to $(\lvert a\rvert -\lvert b\rvert )^2$.

   So (3) holds.

Comment: Thanks, the use of $|a| + |b|$ helps. For those like myself trying to solve with just the material Beckenbach has introduced, if you replace $|a|$ with $\sqrt{a^2}$ in the above, it works.

Comment: Can you provide clarification about why squaring both sides is allowed? Beckenbach introduces the power/root rule for inequalities: If $a \ge b \gt 0$ and $m$ is non-negative integer and $n$ is positive, then $a^\frac{m}{n} \ge b^\frac{m}{n}$

So in your proof, we can square both sides because in (2) both sides are non-negative. If they weren't, squaring both sides wouldn't be valid?

Comment: @JakeKirsch The key here is that $\alpha \leq \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha^2\leq \beta^2$ is only true if both $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$ (and it is indeed true if $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$: take $m=2, n=1$ and $m=2, n=1$ in what you wrote to prove both directions). Since we want to proceed by equivalences, making sure each step is actually an equivalence is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides...

$\cfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}\le \cfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}$

$\cfrac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4}\le \cfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}$

$2a^2+4ab+2b^2\le4(a^2+b^2)$

$2a^2+4ab+2b^2\le4[(a+b)^2-2ab]$

$(a+b)^2\le2(a+b)^2-4ab$

Which proves your inequality, since any numbers $0<x<1$ will produce a positive result, as $-4ab$ will equal to a value smaller than $(a+b)^2$